# There is a delay before html textbox value gets updated after ajax function execution

Tags: javascript, ajax, delay, lag

I am using jcaptcha for image verification in my form. Before the form is submitted I make an ajax call using javascript to validate the text entered by the user corresponding to the image displayed. I get the result and update the value of a textbox(imageVerification). After the function that makes this ajax call is executed I pick up the value from this just updated textbox(imageVerification) for the result.

Here is the problem: I am not able to pick up the value from this textbox(imageVerification).
it always shows up as blank.

Catch: if I use an alert() before picking up the value, I am able to pick up the value correctly. I ran this in firebug debug mode and found out that it works in debug mode even without using the alert.

It seemed there is a delay before which the value in the textbox(imageVerification) gets updated. So i introduced a setTimeout() method and was able to pick up the value.

But I dont feel this is the right solution. I am assuming javascript executes sequentially. So why is my statement which is picking up the value after it has been updated by a method not able to get it immediately. Result is even though the image verification is successfull, my check fails since it is not able to pick up the result value from the textbox.

Also, if I use a simple function to update the textbox(imageVerification) instead of a ajax call, I dont face this problem.

Here is the code I am using for the ajax call.

function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid) {

```
var imageValue = document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['jcaptcha'].value;


    var req = false;
    var parameterString;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        requestContainerContent(req, containerid);
    }

    parameterString = "jcaptcha="+imageValue;
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    req.send(parameterString);

}

function requestContainerContent(req, containerid) {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && (req.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)){

    //document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = req.responseText
    //document.getElementById(containerid).value=req.responseText;
    document.forms['ratingForm'].elements[containerid].value = req.responseText;
    }




}
```

This is the function for image verification:

function validateImage(){

```
if(isBlank(document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['jcaptcha'].value)){
    showError('',"Please enter the text seen in the image above",'jcaptchaError');
    return false;
}
 fetchContainerContent('captchaController','imageVerification');


 var obj = document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['imageVerification'];
//alert('val '+obj.value);
var vall = obj.value;
if(vall=='PASS'){
    return true;

}
else{
    showError('',"Image verification failed. Please refresh image and try again","jcaptchaError");
    return false;
}
```

}

post my call to fetchContainerContent('captchaController','imageVerification'), the value for imageVerification textbox should be set. If I use the alert box which is commented after the fetchContainerContent('captchaController','imageVerification') call it works fine.

Please help me out. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER: Misread program flow on first pass.**

The basic problem is you're trying to get an immediate response from the `validateImage()` function (`return` true or false) when the XMLHttpRequest needs time to complete.

Move the actions taken based on the `return` to their own functions (`validFunction`, `invalidFunction`) and try this:

```
function validateImage() {}
  if(isBlank(document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['jcaptcha'].value)){
      showError('',"Please enter the text seen in the image above",'jcaptchaError');
      return false;
  }

  var obj = document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['imageVerification'];

  validReq = fetchContainerContent('captchaController','imageVerification');
  validReq.onload = function () {
    var validResp = this.reponseText;
    if(validResp=='PASS'){
        validFunction();
    }
    else{
        showError('',"Image verification failed. Please refresh image and try again","jcaptchaError");
        invalidFunction();
    }
  }

  validReq.send(parameterString);
}

function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid) {
var imageValue = document.forms['ratingForm'].elements['jcaptcha'].value;
    var req = false;
    var parameterString;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    parameterString = "jcaptcha="+imageValue;
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return req;
}
```

Comment: Hi BooDooPerson, thanks alot for your response. I was able to solve my problem using a callback mechanism rather than writing the value to an object and then trying to read it, pretty similar to what you have suggested.